# How to combine a list into 1 dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
List A = {'serial': '8BQZ-CCSU-XY36'}, {'serial': 'IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM'}, {'serial': '1ZQN-FXHB-FTXT'}]
```

Since I need to send it over my Django html template, how can I make it to a dict ? Other than that, it also require the key `serial` to be different for every value because dict doesnt accept duplicate keys.

So my idea was making my `List A` to dict that have different keys name like `serial1`, `serial2`,`serial3` (depend on how many data user input.)

So my question is how can I make my List A to a dict and iterate the `serial` key based on how many input?

Expected Output:

```
List A = {'serial1': '8BQZ-CCSU-XY36', 'serial2': 'IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM', 'serial3': '1ZQN-FXHB-FTXT'}]
```

Comment: If you need to create useless dummy keys, why not use a simple list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k+str(i+1): v for i,d in enumerate(List_A) for k,v in d.items()}
```

output:

```
{'serial1': '8BQZ-CCSU-XY36',
 'serial2': 'IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM',
 'serial3': '1ZQN-FXHB-FTXT'}
```

input:

```
List_A = [{'serial': '8BQZ-CCSU-XY36'},
          {'serial': 'IEAJ-NVIS-VMKM'},
          {'serial': '1ZQN-FXHB-FTXT'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dic = {}
for j, i in enumerate(listA):
    j = j+1
    for key,val in i.items():
        dic[key+j] = val
```

Comment: This won't work as all the dictionaries have the same key, you need to increment the key somehow ;)